# Finding the total capacitance?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, capacitance

I am in high school and I am trying to solve this problem but I have not encountered problems like these before. How would you got about total capacitance questions for more complicated circuits?
[image: 1]

Comment: This is reminiscent of a wheatstone bridge in parallel with an extra element, and with capacitors instead of resistors. I remember a teacher giving us a wheatstone bridge as extra credit when I was in high school. I'd recommend taking a look at that analysis if you're still confused.

Answer (score 11):

You may use a symmetry argument. The two nodes in the middle top and middle bottom are, as far as the circuit is concerned, identical. Hence, these nodes will be at the same voltage, and we can't differentiate from this situation and the situation where those nodes are connected with a wire, shorting the vertical capacitor. We conclude that the behavior of the circuit won't change if we replace the vertical capacitor with a wire.

Then, the circuit becomes a manageable combination of parallel and series capacitors, which you should know how to combine!

Comment: * if we replace the vertical capacitor with a wire.*  Why bother with a wire and just remove the capacitor.

Comment: @Farcher When you say remove the capacitor do you mean replace the connection between the top and middle bottom nodes with an open circuit?

Comment: @Farcher because the symmetry argument forces the voltages to be the same at the two nodes, and removing the wire doesn't cause that to happen in general (but it does in this case)

Comment: @BobD Yes, as in this circuit, which is akin to a balanced Wheatstone Bridge, the potentail difference between the top and bottom nodes is zero so it does not matter what is is isn't connected.

Comment: @Farcher Though in this particular case there's no difference, I think it has more pedagogical value for our reasoning to carefully go from recognizing the nodes are at the same voltage to replacing the capacitor with a closed circuit. To replace the capacitor with an open circuit, it's more helpful to reason that no current flows between the nodes instead, which obviously arises from the same argument, just two different ways of framing it.

Answer (score 5):

That feels honestly a bit of a trick question (at least for a high school class).

In most of these problems it's typically best to redraw it in some sort of a standard form which makes it easier to see what's going on.

[image]

Now it's easier to see what's happening. The "trick" part here is that all capacitances are the same. Therefore both C1/C2 and C3/C4 split the voltage in half and so the voltage across C6 becomes zero. That mean no current is flowing through C6 and you simply remove it from the circuit.

Interestingly enough you can either replace it with a wire or just leave it open. In either case the voltage and current of the branch remain zero. You will end up with two different circuits, but the result will still be the same!

Then the whole thing becomes much easier. The total capacitance is simply (C1 series C2)+(C3 series C4) + C5.

If the the capacitances are NOT the same you would have to apply loop and node analysis which feels a bit harsh for high school physics.